# setState in React's useEffect dependency array

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, use-effect

What's the idea behind defining the setState values inside useEffect's dependency array?

```js
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState();
...
useEffect(() => {
  // Do something
  setSomeState('some value');
}, [setSomeState]);
```

```sh
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setSomeState'.
Either include it or remove the dependency array.
eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

Not exactly sure if this example would cause eslint to ask to define `setSomeState` in the dependency array, but I have seen this kind of moments when writing with useEffect.  What is React listening to in this case?  My understanding is that `useEffect` listens for changes in the values in the dependency array, but would `setSomeState` ever change?  What am I missing here?

Comment: It's written on [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html):
`React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In this case, no, the `useState` setter function will never change, but `useEffect` doesn't know it is a function from another hook, it just sees a function.

Consider this use case:

```
const MyComponent = ({ onUpdate }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    // state updated, call onUpdate callback with state
    onUpdate(state);
  }, [onUpdate, state]);
  return ...
}
```

Now parent component can, given

```
<MyComponent onUpdate={onUpdateHandler} />
```

define `onUpdateHandler` as

```
let onUpdateHandler = console.log;
```

then later change it while still mounted

```
onUpdateHandler = state => dispatch({ type: 'SAVE_STATE', state });
```

By placing the callback in the dependency array the effect hook see the value of `onUpdate` changed and trigger the effect again. If it didn't include the callback then it would continue to console.log state updates instead of now handling it differently.

It is more likely for values to change than it is for functions to change, but function values can change. You likely have an eslinter that is recommending you add all the variables used within the hook to the dependency array, and this will in most cases be the correct thing to do. A few exceptions are for example, when you want an effect to compute **ONLY** when the component mounts by specifying an empty array, or not including some variables that are functions that you **KNOW** will never change during the life of the component, and in these cases you can use the `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` override to unflag it as a warning. Caution though, as this will disable the linting checks so it is possible for bugs to creep in if not paying attention.

Comment: So, if I have: `const [foo, setFoo] = useState(whatever);` and I use `foo` and `setFoo` inside my `useEffect` and `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` says they should be in the dependency list, is the tool just flat-out wrong? And if so, this being SUCH a common case, why would anyone EVER use it?

Comment: @ipmcc I am not sure I follow what you are asking, or what you *really* want to know. If both `foo` and `setFoo` are referenced in the hook callback, they are dependencies, and if they are missing the linter will warn you about it.