# Why a set function in dependency array of useEffect()?

Tags: react-hooks

Understand dependency lists out all **as soon as any of them is changed will run whatever in the useEffect**. Mui-data-grid pagination demo, [line 75](https://codesandbox.io/s/ctgknt?file=/demo.tsx:2055-2064), dependency has `setRowCountState` which is a function:

```
const [rowCountState, setRowCountState] = React.useState(rowCount || 0);
React.useEffect(() => {
    setRowCountState((prevRowCountState) =>
      rowCount !== undefined ? rowCount : prevRowCountState,
    );
  }, [rowCount, setRowCountState]);
```

If a reference execution is a trigger, it will then create an infinite loop which needs `outCallBack`. But it doesn't have one. So what a function in dependency array serves?

**Update** The suggested answer changes the function implementation which is not the case here. I'd like to point out that Not everyone has the same intellectual level, while answer A understood by person A, it may require answer B for person B. Vice versa. Appreciate it if this is not closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState in React's useEffect dependency array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709304/setstate-in-reacts-useeffect-dependency-array)

Comment: @cSharp Thanks for the suggestion. The suggested answer use a case of `setState` function changes implementation does not apply here.